# Python/SQL: Storing a sequence

Tags: python, sql, pattern-matching, gtfs

I have the following table (`schedule`) in my database (250K rows):

| id | route_id | route_long_name | trip_id | direction_id | stop_id | stop_name | arrival_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 70111001900000 | Red line | 14010000574353508 | 0 | 9022001001281076 | Central station | 04:42:00 |
| 2 | 70111001900001 | Yellow line | 14010000574345371 | 0 | 9022001001282313 | Hospital | 04:43:00 |
| 3 | 70111001900002 | Blue line | 14010000574245335 | 0 | 9022001001224379 | Spooner st. | 04:44:00 |

The data that resides inside it comes from [GTFS static](https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs) feed in my town. It is fairly standardized and contains descriptions for each vehicle type, route, station and more.

The problem occurs when the static database is enriched with updates coming from [GTFS realtime](https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs-realtime/guides/trip-updates) feed. TripUpdates feed does not specify which line the vehicle being driven belongs to if **it is added to handle sudden increase in number of travelers or if the previous vehicle is broken**.

**TripUpdates**:

```
trip_update {
 trip {
   trip_id: "14010000574353508"      # Exists in the database
   start_date: "20220204"
   schedule_relationship: SCHEDULED  # Trip is scheduled, everything is OK
 }
 stop_time_update {
   stop_sequence: 72
   arrival {
     delay: 147
     time: 1643833304
     uncertainty: 0
   }
   departure {
     delay: 147
     time: 1643833304
     uncertainty: 0
   }
   stop_id: "9022001001281076"       # Exists in the database, "Central station"
 }
 vehicle {
   id: "9031001000158703"
 }
}
trip_update {
 trip {
   trip_id: "14010513667077909"      # Does not exist in the database
   start_time: "21:06:00"
   start_date: "20220204"
   schedule_relationship: ADDED      # New trip, needs to be added to the database 
 }
 stop_time_update {
   stop_sequence: 1
   arrival {
     delay: 0
     time: 1643833260
   }
   departure {
     delay: 0
     time: 1643833260
   }
   stop_id: "9022001001282313"       # Exists in the database, "Hospital"
 }
 stop_time_update {
   stop_sequence: 2
   arrival {
     delay: 0
     time: 1643833299
   }
   departure {
     delay: 0
     time: 1643833299
   }
   stop_id: "9022001001282314"       # Exists in the database, "Hogwarts", definitely Yellow line 
 }
 vehicle {
   id: "9031001002500015"
 }
 timestamp: 1643829559
}
```

What I am trying to do is to determine which line the vehicle belongs to based on stops it makes and once I am certain about it, add it to the database. To better show what I mean, I drew the following example map of subway lines.

[image: subway lines example]

With the example of my subway map:

- If a trip starts at **B1** and goes to **B7** - add it as the Blue line to the database.
- If a trip starts at **X1** and goes to **Y5** - add it as the Yellow line to the database.
- If a trip starts at **X1** and goes to **X3** - add it as "Extra line" to the database.

What I already have is a table with `stop_id`s belonging to each subway line:

Red line:

- 9022001001281079 - Spooner st.
- 9022001001281078 - Big Hotel
- 9022001001281077 - Central park
- 9022001001281076 - **Central station**

Blue line:

- 9022001001221005 - Airport
- 9022001001221004 - John Johnsson st.
- 9022001001221003 - City church
- 9022001001221002 - **Central station**

Yellow line:

- 9022001001282314 - Hogwarts
- 9022001001282313 - Hospital
- 9022001001282312 - **Central station**

My program is written in Python and uses sqlite3 database. I have experimented with if statements, which resulted in spaghetti code that can not be maintained or read. I have also tried with different table connections and translating station names into binary patterns, which also resulted in the same spaghetti code unfortunately.

**My question is** if there is any way to handle patterns in either Python or SQL (think it is more about SQL) to assign a line to the trip based on what stops it is expected to have?

So basically (pseudo code):

```
IF anything BETWEEN 9022001001281079 AND 9022001001281071 -> "Red line"
IF anything BETWEEN 9022001001221005 AND 9022001001209996 -> "Blue line"
IF anything BETWEEN 9022001001282314 AND 9022001001282307 -> "Yellow line"
ELSE -> "Extra line"
```

**Keep in mind that `stop_id`s are not sequence numbers.** IDs provided in this post are just examples, in real GTFS feed, one station may have ID 9022001001221005 and the next one (on same line) might have ID 9022003201321094.

**Update 1**:

SQL CASE and BETWEEN will not work here.

I tried the solution provided in comments (using SQL BETWEEN) and detected some issues.

After I extracted MAX and MIN values from `stop_id`s for subway lines I get the following scheme:

**Red line**: 9022001001011003 - 9022001002851002

**Blue line**: 9022001001051005 - 9022001003481002

**Yellow line**: 9022001001011001 - 9022001001951002

Because the first part of `stop_id` is always the same, I exclude it in further description.

If a train moves from `1011003` to `1011007`, SQL CASE and BETWEEN will not be able to detect subway line correctly as this range is true for both Red and Yellow lines.

Comment: SQL has a `BETWEEN` operator.

Comment: Unfortunately, `BETWEEN` will not work here. I tried to build several SQL queries with BETWEEN parameter and it gets messy pretty fast.

Comment: Another solution I'm thinking of is to use the following (pseudo): `IF stop_name1 & stop_name2 IN all_green_stop -> 'Green line'`. In this solution I create a list of all stops for each line and compare first two stop names in TripUpdate feed, if a trip has `ADDED` status.

Comment: This is more about finding a logical solution, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `CASE` expression in SQL, using the `BETWEEN` operator.

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN stop_id BETWEEN 9022001001281071 AND 9022001001281079 THEN 'Red line'
        WHEN stop_id BETWEEN 9022001001209996 AND 9022001001221005 THEN 'Blue line'
        WHEN stop_id BETWEEN 9022001001282307 AND 9022001001282314 THEN 'Yellow line'
        ELSE 'Extra Line'
    END AS line
```

Note that `BETWEEN` requires the lower number first, so I reversed the orders of your stop IDs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Barmar. I tested your solution and provided an update. Unfortunately, I don't think it solves my issue.

Comment: I don't really understand your application well, and you haven't shown the table structure. I was just showing how to translate your pseudo-code into SQL. If the pseudo-code isn't really correct, then obviously this won't work.

Comment: I guess I'm a bit unclear about the rest of the application but the issue itself is quite complex. As I wrote previously, my issue is that `stop_id`s are not sequence numbers. There are no `1,2,3,X,10,11` sequence. What I thought was that there is other way of defining a pattern, without relying on ranges or between cases.